# Do I need to put a colon or dash here?

Tags: пунктуация

I'm currently writing some kind of journalistic-style essay about ecology problems, and here, I came up with a sentence, in which I don't know what punctuation to use:

1. "Первая причина: истребление животных"
2. "Первая причина - истребление животных"

Which one is correct? I'm more inclined to believe that the second one is preferable since the dash can be replaced with "- это", and I know that before "это" I definitely want to put dashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the meaning of your sentence.

Your sentence is most likely a simple subject-predicate one, which you would convey in English as "the first reason is the extermination of animals". In this case, you should use an em-dash.

Rosenthal et al., *Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация*, § 2.5.1:

> Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым при отсутствии связки, если оба главных члена предложения выражены существительными в форме именительного падежа: *Одиночество в творчестве — тяжёлая штука (Ч.); Следующая станция — Мытищи, Московские игры — прекрасная академия спортивного творчества (Газ.)*.

It may also be that your sentence is an marginal case: a headline with a subheading or an explanatory phrase ("the first reason — namely, the extermination of animals —"), or something like that.

In that case, you may want to use a colon instead:

> Двоеточие ставится в заголовках, распадающихся на две части с чётким интонационным делением, отличающихся смысловой насыщенностью, предельной краткостью и нередко эмоциональной выразительностью. Первая часть называет общую проблему, место действия, лицо, а вторая — содержит конкретизацию названного в первой части: *Экономическая реформа: опыт, проблемы трудности; Разоружение: концепция, проблемы, механизм; Россия — Западная Европа: выгоды и перспективы сотрудничества; Звёздный рейс: работа на отлично!; Новый герой: поиски и находки; Женщина: семья и работа; Юпитер: планета или звезда?; Перевозка айсбергов: мифы и реальность; Смена правительства: старое наследство, новые возможности; Генетика: стратегия и тактика; Космические лучи: старые или новые?; Энергетика: начало и будущее; Многоэтажные улицы: спасение или бедствие?; Рентгеновский лазер: поиски и надежды.*

> Двоеточие в бессоюзном сложном предложении, распадающемся на две части, ставится… если вторая часть (одно или несколько предложений) разъясняет, раскрывает содержание первой части (между обеими частями можно вставить слово "а именно"), например: *Страшная мысль мелькнула в. уме моем: я вообразил ее в руках разбойников (Пушкин); В самом деле, шинель Акакия Акакиевича имела какое-то странное устройство: воротник ее уменьшался с каждым годом более и более, ибо служил на подтачивание других частей (Гоголь); Сделай план квартиры: как расположены комнаты, где двери, где окна, где что стоит (Горький).*